# Building a JSON-LD Schema dynamically

Tags: json, json-ld

is there a way to dynamically insert the "value" of my "variables"?

Like

1. "url:" 'generic rule valid for any single specific webpage of mydomain'",
2. "name: " 'generic rule valid for any single specific webpage of mydomain'" ,
3. "alternateName": " 'generic rule valid for any single specific webpage of mydomain' ", etc.

And doing this **without using Google Tag Manager or without php and ld+json** but only including "generic rules or parameters"?

Comment: In which language/framework?

Comment: I'm tryng to put a ld+json in my html pages of my website...my problem is that in every page there are some "variables" lik in the code below:

`<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "MedicalCondition",
  "alternateName": "Parkinson-disease",
  "name": "Parkinson"
}
</script>`
If you look at "name" and "alternateName" you will notice that every page will have a specific name like "Abdominal aortic aneurysm";  "aneurysm" etc...

P.s.
Srry for the editing and re-edit of this comment but i'm newbbb :)

Comment: And how do you get this data in the actual content? Do you write it by hand or do you use a tool / a programming language? You said that you don’t use GTM or PHP, so what *do* you use? -- E.g., do you use a CMS, Python/Ruby/etc., or do you write your HTML files manually (i.e., they are static)?